# Passing app_data to Facebook page tab with the new pretty URL

Tags: facebook

Facebook just changed their url from https://www.facebook.com/`pagename`?sk=app_`appid`&app_data=`anystring` to https://www.facebook.com/`pagename`/app/`appid`

In this new URL, I tried passing app_data via https://www.facebook.com/`pagename`/app/`appid`?app_data=`anystring`.

However, the page tab did not pass the app_data to the signed request.

What's the way pass app_data now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very new bug, posted at the earliest November 24th 10:35pm.
I would recommend subscribing to it here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/581651058655899/